# Übersetzung von "I don't play football"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage, negation

Wie übersetzt man

> I don't play football.

ins Deutsche?

> (a) Ich spiele keinen Fußball.
>
> (b) Ich spiele kein Fußball.
>
> (c) Ich spiele nicht Fußball.

(a) kann man begründen, dass Fußball ein maskulines Nomen ist und deshalb mit *keinen* verneint werden muss. Aber man kann Fußball als ein Spiel denken, und da *Spiel* neuter ist, kann man (b) verwenden. Es endet doch nicht hier. Man kann *Fußball spielen* als eine Phrase denken wie *Auto fahren* oder *Rad fahren*. In dem Falle muss man die ganze Phrase verneinen, und daher sollte man (c) sagen.

Welche ist eigentlich die richtige Übersetzung?

Comment: Auch wenn (b) in den Antworten als falsch oder umgangssprachlich bezeichnet wird: Ich würde stark zu (b) tendieren, weil für mich die Sportarten Fußball/Basketball/Baseball etc. Neutrum sind. Das jeweilige Sportgerät ist bei mir Maskulinum. Also: Ich sehe keinen Fußball (=Mask., Spielgerät); ich mag kein Fußball (=Neutr., Sportart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(c) ist definitiv korrekt, es geht eigentlich nur noch darum, ob evtl. andere Varianten ebenfalls verwendet werden können. Umgangssprachlich wohl ja.

Da die Tätigkeit *Fußball spielen* heißt, sollte die Negation m. E ganz einfach mit *nicht* gebildet werden:

> Ich laufe. Ich laufe nicht.
>
> Ich spiele Fußball. Ich spiele nicht Fußball.

Nur dort, wo es nicht um feststehende Kombinationen geht und man eine Unterscheidung machen möchte, kann man auch kein oder keine nehmen:

> Ich tanze keinen Tango (aber Walzer sehr wohl). Ich trinke keinen Rotwein (lieber Weißwein.)

Answer (score 0):

Korrekt sind (a) und (c). Umgangssprachlich sagt man häufig (b); mehr und mehr sieht man, dass die Akkusativdeklination unter den Tisch gekehrt wird. Folglich sind alle drei Variante durchaus akzeptabel.

Comment: Kann man wirklich "keinen Fußball" spielen, obwohl sowohl "einen" als auch "den" Fußball zu spielen eine andere Bedeutung haben als Fußball zu spielen?

Comment: „… unter den Tisch gekehrt wird“ ist wohl eine Katachrese aus „unter den Tisch fallen“ und „etwas unter den Teppich kehren“.

Comment: Ich benutze (b); ich meine aber, die Akkusativendung dabei nicht unter den Teppich zu kehren, sondern die Sportart "Fußball" hier als Neutrum zu gebrauchen.

Comment: @Chris Für mich ist auch der Sport "der Fußball". Ich verwende übrigens auch nahezu ausschließlich Variante (b).

Comment: @Em1: Ich habe auch schon Kommentatoren gehört, die Dinge sagten wie "XY spielt schönen Fußball". Das hört sich für mich trotzdem irgendwie falsch an. Noch falscher würde es sich für mich übrigens bei "Baseball", "Basketball" usw. anhören. Hmmm...